# PHP - Send HTTP Request to local script

Tags: php, http

I'm trying to use one PHP script on my server that calls other scripts.

The main script, called `call.php`, is in the `public_html` folder, so I can send an HTTP request to it using `my_website.com/call.php?action=some_script_name&arg1=value&arg2=some_other_value`.

I already have a method to form the new request (and execute it), if the `action` script is in `public_html`. For example, if `some_script.php` was located at `/public_html/scripts/some_script.php`, my HTTP request would be `my_website.com/scripts/some_script.php?arg1=value&arg2=some_other_value`.

I have that done already, and it works correctly. However, I want to send requests to scripts that are NOT in `public_html` (or any subdirectory of that). For example, if I have a script under `/lib/otherscript.php`, I want to call that as well.

I tried a request such as `../lib/otherscript.php?args_here`, but that did not work.

Is this possible, and if so, how can I accomplish this?

Edit:

The actual file structure of the (shared) server looks like this (for this example):

```
/
    public_html/
        call.php
        scripts/
            some_script.php

    lib/
        otherscript.php
```

Comment: wait, is the lib folder outside of your apache documentroot? (assuming apache)

Answer (score 1):

You can't access something outside `public_html` via HTTP; that's the whole point of the `public_html` directory. You have a few options:

- Create a wrapper that is publicly accessible to call the functionality in `public_html`. The best way to do this is either a class or a function that takes as parameters the arguments from your URL.
- Use the command line interpreter.

Either way, you may need to do some user authentication if the functionality is sensitive. If it's harmless, you can put it in `public_html`. If it's not, you need authentication/authorization checks.

*Edited because I misread your question originally.*

Comment: Is it possible to call the script in another fashion, while also providing arguments?

Comment: Nope. You either put it in `public_html` or put something in `public_html` that invokes the functionality you want and passes appropriate arguments.

Comment: Note: @yaa110's answer is correct, but it's the same as my first bullet above. The point is that you can include a file outside `public_html`, but you can't access it directly via HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `cPanel` you can access php files outside `public_html` folder using absolute url, e.g.: `<?php require_once('/home/username/lib/otherscript.php'); ?>` now you can post parameters to any script within `public_html` folder at witch you have included `otherscript.php`.

Note: You have to use your cPanel user name in absolute address.